# sbt jline dependency not found

Tags: scala, sbt, jline

In my local repo for scala/scala github project([here](https://github.com/scala/scala)), jline dependency is set as 2.14.5. I change it to 3.1.3, but dependency is not resolved when I try to build the project.

How to get it resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `groupId` of jline 3.x has changed from `jline` to `org.jline`.
Try with the following:

`val jlineDep          = "org.jline"              % "jline"                            % versionProps("jline.version")`